# "rotating equipment" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german, technical-terminology

> **Equipment Engineering**
>   Data sheets of the rotating equipment and aggregates, first issue

Bei ProZ, LEO und linguee habe ich nichts gefunden. Vielleicht "Drehgeräte"?

Branche "Anlagenbau" 
Es geht um eine Salzanlage. "Rotating equipment" steht nur in diesem Kontext im Text.

Comment: Welche Branche? Autos, Turbinen, Zentrifungen, Handmixer, Haartrockner, Waschmaschinen, Kernkraftwerke? Ich denke, diese Info brauchen wir schon, um das *Drehding* korrekt zu beschreiben.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob das hilfreich ist, aber auf Wikipedia gibt es einen deutschen Artikel dazu, in dem behauptet wird, dass dieser Begriff "auch im deutschen Sprachgebrauch Verwendung findet." Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_Equipment. Vielleicht ist der Begriff in entsprechenden Personenkreisen so bekannt.

Comment: Also wahrscheinlich allgemein gesehen eine *Drehvorrichtung*...

Comment: In meinem Metier, Zahnheilkunde, wird der Begriff "rotierende Instrumente" benutzt. Wird wohl in anderen Branchen anders sein.

Comment: Es geht um eine Salzanlage. "Rotating equipment" steht nur in diesem Kontext im Text.

Comment: Branche "Anlagenbau"

Answer (score 4):

Im Maschinenbau etc. spricht man hier von Rotationsanlage(n)

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass eine Drehbühne gemeint ist. Aggregate sind eher Pumpen, Rührer usw.

Comment: Von einer Drehbühne rede ich auch gar nicht. Die von dir genannten Pumpen und Rüher sind Arten von Rotationsanlagen.

Comment: Kapiert! ... +1

Answer (score 1):

Da hier noch Kontext zu fehlen scheint:

Neben Rotationsanlagen wären da noch
rotierende Geräte,  rotierenden Teile, rotierende Anlage, rotierende Einrichtung, rotierende Maschine, rotierende Ausrüstung, drehende Vorrichtungen, oder ganz schlicht **Rotor** in Betracht zu ziehen.

Die genaue Bedeutung ist in der englischen Vokabel nicht allzu eindeutig enthalten?
Verglichen mit einer [dokumentierten Übersetzung](https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/rotating+equipment+engineer.html) von:

> sustained implementation of a well thought-out repair concept - also in the field of Rotating Equipment & Valve Service.   –– wirkungsvolle und nachhaltige Umsetzung eines durchdachten Instandhaltungskonzepts - auch im Bereich Maschinen- und Antriebstechnik.

Eine weitere [Liste mit Beispielen](http://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/ROTATING+EQUIPMENT) lässt da ähnlich viel Spielraum

Und da es sich sowieso um einen Fachtext handelt, kann man das ohne viel Aussehen auch unübersetzt lassen.
Siehe Kommentar von Igor O:

> Ich weiß nicht, ob das hilfreich ist, aber auf Wikipedia gibt es einen deutschen Artikel dazu, in dem behauptet wird, dass dieser Begriff "auch im deutschen Sprachgebrauch Verwendung findet." Siehe de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_Equipment. Vielleicht ist der Begriff in entsprechenden Personenkreisen so bekannt.

Comment: fyi: OP hat den Kontext in ihren Kommentaren ergänzt

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde das

- angetriebene Bauteile *(allgemein, Antrieb von außen)*

oder

- Bauteile mit Antrieb *(Antrieb eingebaut)*

nennen. Ob's rotiert oder schwingt ist nämlich klapsegal für den Energiebedarf. Meist tut es ja sogar beides.